# How can I monitor who is online and their CPU Usage in SAS Management Console?

Tags: sas

I am tasked to manage company's SAS server (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 64 bit(Santiago)
As the title suggests, I need to see who is using SAS Enterprise Guide and SAS Enterprise Mining  software and How much CPU they consume on their jobs while they are working. I learned that SAS does not have a built in tool for that and I have to use a 3rd party software. I am seeking a mostly graphical tool if it exists.

Comment: What software is on your server, is it SAS Enterprise BI Server?  And are you the SAS Administrator (meaning you have the unrestricted account password and can run SAS Management Console)?  And are you looking for "real time" or historical reporting?

Comment: Questions about how to use a particular software are off-topic!

Comment: Hello BellevueBob, I need real time reporting mostly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what sort of ready-made graphical tools might be available for your particular OS. However, one option you could investigate further would be to execute a Linux `top` command via a filename pipe statement in SAS. You could then use this as the infile in a data step, and then get SAS to produce some graphical output from it.

It may take quite a bit of fiddling around to get exactly what you want, but if you persevere you should be able to produce the sort of output that you're interested in - e.g. the total CPU time / number of processes per user etc over a given interval.